# How to repeat text box in every page in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to repeat textbox in every page without giving it on the page header in SSRS. Because before this textbox I have few data to be displayed in the 1st page. So if I put both in page header and making visibility hide for the data that should appear only in 1st page, then in other pages excess header space will come..
So is it possible to repeat text box or table in every page?

Comment: I've up voted the question and I think still the solution is not available in newer version also. BTW good question.

Comment: Ridiculous there is no easy way to achieve this. I just want to have the same text in every page and in the body section.

Answer (score 2):

You can look into the "RepeatWith" property of your textbox, which should appear on every page where the target component will be present. It should work even if there are other elements before, between or after them.

You could also put the textbox in a table's header, put the rest of your report inside that table's body, and then repeat the table header on every page. However this sounds very painful to implement and maintain, I would avoid that solution unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: "RepeatWith" property depends on a data element, table or whatever. Normally this type of request is something not dependant on the data it self, like the header. A very common request is to have a rotated text on the edge of the report. How to achieve this?